# after_switch_theme not working in a class?

Tags: url-rewriting, actions

Here is my class (by way of example)

`after_switch_theme` is being stupid and refuses to fire.

```
class myPlugin(){

    __construct(){
        add_action('after_switch_theme', array($this, 'rewrite'));
    }
    public function rewrite(){

        if(function_exists('the_other_theme_rewrite'))
            return;

        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('typename', 'typename/%year%%postname%/', true, 1);
        add_rewrite_rule('typename/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?typename=$matches[2]', 'top');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();        
    }

}
```

...more or less thats what it is. I typed it in directly here.

It definitely is not firing though. Why isn't it firing? I just want it to fire! Is that so much to ask? :D

So - why no results?

Comment: Have you initiated the class some where?

Comment: Also use proper syntax, `__construct(){` should be `public function __construct(){`

Comment: Yeah, thats all set up properly. SOrry for the whacky class example - I'm actually using the grunt-init wp-boilerplate method. Everything is instantiating - just dead-air with the action I'm trying to set up.

Comment: Its the oddest thing - the method is obviously being called, but no re-write seems to be happening.

Comment: I think your problem is the same described in the question [Rewrite rules goes away](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112633/rewrite-rules-goes-away). Possible duplicated.